# Why does matrix-matrix product come close to the peak performance of a system?

Tags: matrices

In this [paper](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:141511/FULLTEXT01.pdf), I read " The most important operation is
GEMM (GEneral Matrix Multiply), which typically deﬁnes the practical peak
performance of a computer system."

But why? Why does matrix-matrix product come close to or even define the peak performance of a system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GEMM exercises, *one helluva lot*, several essential features of any computer system:  (i.) memory access, since so much fetching of data has to occur for large matrices;  (ii.) ALU performance, since there is so much arithmetic to be done, *viz.* $\sum a[i] * b[i]$ for arrays
$a[i], b[i]$; (iii.)  control flow , since so much looping and/or (possibly recursive) subroutine calling must generally be done.  So GEMM provides a nice mix of at least these three areas of functionality.  And since the tests make the most sense for large matrices, it is relatively easy to generate good statistics from running GEMM-like codes.

***Edit:  Material added in response to oasisweng's comment:***  The following is too long for even two comments, so I've added it here:  it's not just that a large number of operations are required, it is also *very important* that the codes exercise different functional units such as memory, ALUs, controllers, preferably in a manner which *forces them to interact*.  Only then can we find out if they do so efficiently, don't stall one another, etc.  If the matrices are small, then you will exercise things differently than if you have *large* matrices, so the tests have to be run with a variety of input data.  Obviously, if all you have is a small number of small matrices, the test(s) won't tell you very much.  But a *large* number of smallish matrices or a smallish number of *large* matrices will exercise the machine in different ways, each of which will be telling.  We *are* implicitly assuming that the mix of initial data is both large and heterogeneous enough to significantly exercise the machine.  There's no fixed lower bound for "big enough", but as machines get more powerful the size of the data sets tend to grow.  In conclusion, there's very little which is absolutely fixed, so you have to design test suites which are sufficiently varied.  Finally, there are a couple of books on computer architecture by Patterson and Hennessy which address these kinds of questions very well;  google around and you'll find them.  ***End of Edit.***

My take on it anyway.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!***

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer! So what I learned here in summary is that the big quantity of calculations GEMM, or aka BLAS Lvl 3(?), requires is what makes it so good for determining the performance of a computer system? What if the matrices involved is relatively small for GEMM did not specify the size, then how can GEMM still determine computer performance? Are we implicitly defining the matrices doing GEMM is considerable enough to measure the performance? How do we know in what degree a matrix is "considerable enough"?

Comment: @oasisweng:  my response to your comment was rather lengthy, so I edited it into my answer.

Comment: I truly appreciate your answer:-)

Comment: @ oasisweng,:  thanks!  Glad to help out!  And thanks for the "acceptance"!

Answer (score 1):

Peak performance is the speed at which a CPU can execute a sequence of instructions. The problem is that on the CPU architectures ubiquitous since the 90's, characterised by a hierarchy of memory with different speeds, transfer from memory to the processor registers is the key limiting factor: most algorithms test the speed of data transfer from memory to the CPU as much as the CPU speed itself. Some orders of magnitudes: 1 cycle to add or multiply two floats stored in register; about 4 cycles to load from L1 cache to register; about 10 cycles from L2 cache; from 40 to a few hundred cycles from L3 cache. Thus the most efficient operations are those such that once a chunk of data has been moved upward through this memory hierarchy, as many floating point operations are performed on it that do not require further data motion.

It turns out that matrix multiplication is well suited here. Consider the multiplication of two square matrices:

$$
C_{ij} = \sum_{p=1}^n A_{ip} B_{pj}.
$$

This requires to move $O(n^2)$ matrix elements from memory to the CPU and it will then take $O(n^3)$ flops. Thus the cost of moving each matrix element is amortised over $O(n)$ flops. This means that the speed at which the processor can execute operations is really tested here. Now compare with a matrix-vector product:

$$
y_i = \sum_{p=1}^n A_{ij} x_j.
$$

This requires to move $O(n^2)$ elements to the registers, as for matrix multiplication, but now it will take only $O(n^2)$ flops. That means that for each flop there is a memory move. Thus this hardly exercises the speed at which the CPU can operate as it tests the speed of the memory transfers on an equal footing.